# Gatsby images - scaling and lazy loading images in markdown html

Tags: graphql, markdown, gatsby, contentful, gatsby-image

I have a lot of markdown files that I've imported into Contentful with images linked inside of them. The images link to external websites like Imgur for the source.

I'm trying to get the images to scale up and lazy load like you can do using the `Gatsby Image API`. The problem is that the images are all within the one html node due to how the markdown is processed.

The markdown is being set on the page using:

```
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: body.childMarkdownRemark.html }}
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? I feel like there is some way to chain Gatsby plugins to download the images locally from the html and then create nodes in GraphQL to handle this but I'm not sure. Ideally I don't want to have to change the markdown files to point to Contentful assets due to it not being easy to migrate to other solutions in the future.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I've successfully used Gatsby-Image to do what you're asking, but there's not a whole lot of fine-grained control in that.  However, it should support 90% of use cases.  https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/using-gatsby-image/